# Getting city and country from NSTimeZone

Tags: iphone, nstimezone

I'd like to (at least) get the name of the country for a time zone. This is not provided by any of the potential methods:

- name,
- localizedName:locale:,
- description

I notice that the built in iPhone clock App has access to this information, as it describes London as "London, England".

Thanks.

Comment: Please update us with how you did this if you figure it out. I'm also interested on how to do this.

Comment: He Ben, I didn't get any further. There are some city databases about that might be useful for performing this kind of look up though. Take a look at: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=714539, http://www.geobytes.com/GeoWorldMap.zip and http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/worldcities/ to get started.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: System Preferences > Date & Time > Time Zone on OS X shows similar information, and the map there credits Geonames.org.  Perhaps worth digging in to what OS X is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it works different with the built-in clock. There is a database of cities of which each has a country and a timezone. 
And what would you expect from `[myGMT city]`? Dublin or Casablanca?

Comment: Are you aware of this database being exposed, or do you believe it to be custom code in the clock app?

An NSTimeZone instance does not simply represent a GMT offset (as I think you are implying with your last sentence, but I'm not sure), they represent (as stated in the documentation) "geopolitical regions", and as far as I can see, are always rooted on a specific city. It is quite reasonable to show the country this city is in, as the clock app does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the [`timeZoneWithName:data:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneWithName:data:) method, the filesystem has timezone information located at `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

I have no idea what the format of the files is, or if you can even read them from the application sandbox, but that's likely how the Clock application gets the information.

Comment: Thanks – The info at that path is related to the TZ database, or Zoneinfo database. It's a standard open data file for representing time zone info used by many architectures – lots of info on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo. The zoneinfo file doesn't provide the country a city is in, however, so I don't think the clock would be using this.

Comment: fyi: the link embedded in the answer has rotted